# create custom LAMP distribution like XAMPP

Tags: php, c, makefile, lamp, configure

I wish to make a self contained LAMP <strike>distro</strike> software package from  source with at least the following:
* php must have mysqli, ldap and GD support
* all required .so's must be included (like libpng needed by GD) (self contained)

I managed to make one but i keep patching quirks to it, SO i thought to start from a wide-used one like XAMPP but i can't find the source that builds it (some shell script where it writes all the configure options, involved sources  etc).

*Where can i find such a script/informations ?*

I need this so my users have an easy out of the box install for my software, they are not LAMP admins.

*I need the configure options of XAMPP packages or similar.*

Comment: This may be better suited for serverfault.com

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are the configure options that I used to build my own lamp stack.
They are extracted from CentOS rpm lamp packages.

```
# APACHE
cd httpd-2.2.14/
./configure \
--prefix=/opt/clamp \
--sysconfdir=/opt/clamp/etc \
--enable-auth-dbm \
--enable-cern-meta \
--enable-auth-digest \
--enable-charset-lite \
--enable-deflate \
--enable-expires \
--enable-cache \
--enable-disk-cache \
--enable-file-cache \
--enable-headers \
--enable-info \
--enable-mime-magic \
--enable-proxy \
--enable-proxy-ajp \
--enable-proxy-balancer \
--enable-proxy-connect \
--enable-proxy-ftp \
--enable-proxy-http \
--enable-rewrite \
--enable-so \
--enable-ssl
make
make install
cd ..

# MYSQL
cd mysql-5.1.44/
./configure \
--prefix=/opt/clamp \
--sysconfdir=/opt/clamp/etc \
--libexecdir=/opt/clamp/sbin \
--localstatedir=/opt/clamp/var \
--with-unix-socket-path=/opt/clamp/tmp/mysql.sock
make
make install
cd ..

# LIBS_DEP
yum install freetype
yum install freetype-devel
yum install libjpeg
yum install libjpeg-devel
yum install libpng
yum install libpng-devel
yum install libXpm
yum install libXpm-devel

# PHP
cd php-5.2.13/
./configure \
--prefix=/opt/clamp \
--sysconfdir=/opt/clamp/etc \
--with-apxs2=/opt/clamp/bin/apxs \
--with-config-file-path=/opt/clamp/etc/php.conf \
--disable-debug \
--with-pic \
--disable-rpath \
--without-pear \
--with-bz2 \
--with-curl \
--with-freetype-dir=/usr \
--with-png-dir=/usr \
--enable-gd-native-ttf \
--without-gdbm \
--with-gettext \
--with-gmp \
--with-iconv \
--with-jpeg-dir=/usr \
--with-openssl \
--with-pspell \
--with-zlib \
--with-layout=GNU \
--enable-exif \
--enable-ftp \
--enable-magic-quotes \
--enable-sockets \
--enable-sysvsem --enable-sysvshm --enable-sysvmsg \
--enable-wddx \
--with-kerberos \
--enable-ucd-snmp-hack \
--enable-shmop \
--enable-calendar \
--without-sqlite \
--enable-force-cgi-redirect \
--enable-pcntl \
--with-imap --with-imap-ssl \
--enable-mbstring \
--enable-mbregex \
--with-ncurses \
--with-gd \
--enable-bcmath \
--with-xmlrpc \
--with-ldap --with-ldap-sasl \
--with-mysql=/opt/clamp \
--with-mysqli=/opt/clamp/bin/mysql_config \
--enable-dom \
--with-pgsql \
--enable-soap \
--enable-xmlreader --enable-xmlwriter \
--enable-fastcgi 
make
make install

ln -s /opt/clamp/share/mysql/mysql.server /opt/clamp/bin/mysql.server
mkdir /opt/clamp/tmp
/bin/cp -f /root/clamp/use/etc/* /opt/clamp/etc
/bin/cp -f /root/clamp/use/run /opt/clamp
/bin/cp -f /root/clamp/use/install /opt/clamp

./bin/mysql_install_db --user=clamp \
--basedir=/opt/clamp \
--datadir=/opt/clamp/var

groupadd clamp
useradd -g clamp -s /bin/nologin -d /opt/clamp clamp
chown -R clamp.clamp /opt/clamp


# start first !!!!!!!!!

/opt/clamp/bin/mysqladmin -u root -P 3307 password 123clamp456
/opt/clamp/bin/mysqladmin -u root -p123clamp456 -P 3307 flush-privileges

/opt/clamp/bin/mysql -u root -p123clamp456 -P 3307 -e "CREATE USER 'clamp'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY '123clamp456'";
/opt/clamp/bin/mysql -u root -p123clamp456 -P 3307 -e "update mysql.user set password = PASSWORD('123clamp456') where user='clamp'";
/opt/clamp/bin/mysql -u root -p123clamp456 -P 3307 -e "GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'clamp'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY '123clamp456'";
/opt/clamp/bin/mysql -u root -p123clamp456 -P 3307 -e "GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'clamp'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY '123clamp456'";
/opt/clamp/bin/mysql -u root -p123clamp456 -P 3307 -e "flush privileges";
```

Answer (score 1):

You do realize you can enable these extensions inside XAMPP by just editing the php.ini file?

Also you should use [Imagick](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.imagick.php) (aka ImageMagick) instead of GD, it's substantially faster (around 3x) and more feature rich.  Imagick replaces GD.

I don't see a reason to create a custom installation, just configure the one you have.

Comment: I know about ImageMagick but my software uses libs that sit on top of GD, is fast eough and rich enough for me.

Answer (score 1):

You want to create (and presumably maintain and support) a whole Linux distribution?????!!!!!

And you're expecting a complete answer here????!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

There's no way anyone can provide a proper answer to that - it takes years to learn how to do all that, IIRC there are no one-man Linux distributions currently available.

You might consider having a look at Puppy Linux which comes with a lot of tools for generating custom installations.

Alternatively, it might be a lot simpler to build a reference implementation then distribute it as a virtual machine image (I've recently started playing with [VirtualBox](http://www.virtualbox.org/) which is free, but there are several others out there - Bochs, VMWare....).

Although you seem to be confusing LAMP (which is everything from the OS up) with XAMPP (which only contains the webserver, db, PERL and PHP).

C.

Comment: I added clarifications in the question!